# Intercept Opening Window - C#

Tags: c#, windows, event-handling, window

Is there some way to watch for / intercept a window opening in Windows and then to block said window from opening?  This would be for an application that's already running and I wouldn't want to stop the process, just close the popup window it spawns.

**Update**:

1. A process is already running (e.g. it's in Task Manager) but has no visible windows.
2. At some random time, that process will popup a window
3. I manually close the window (click "OK").
4. The process continues to run at this point and will, again, popup a window a bit later (repeating these steps).

I want to automate step #3, where I have to manually close the popup, by intercepting that window opening and closing it or hiding it or never letting it open in the first place.  I don't want to do this by polling the open windows.  I want to receive some event that a window is about to open.

I do not control this other application, so I can't otherwise change it.  And I don't want to kill the process, itself.

Comment: From opening? You could detect and close it, maybe. Unless the application is very poorly written, or written to cope with you messing with it like this, it's liable to crash.

Comment: So you're trying to detect if the application is already running so a second copy doesn't load?

Comment: Updated question.  Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Important question: Did you write the program that is "already in the Tast Manager" and do you therefore have the source code of that? Or do you want (and have to because you don't have the source code) to write a second program that only closes the popup of the first one?

Comment: The 2nd option... I did not write the program that has the popup.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do what I asked (allow only one instance of a program to run at a time), here is an elegant solution using a [Mutex](http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html).  You can probably copy and paste most of that code to achieve what you want.